# MFC Multiple Select of ListBox Item

Tags: c++, mfc

I am currently trying to figure out, how to select multiple Items from a
`CListBox`.

This is my code

```
//Init listbox
m_Idc_List_Cards.ModifyStyle(0, LBS_EXTENDEDSEL);
//m_Idc_List_Cards.ModifyStyle(0, LBS_MULTIPLESEL);
m_Idc_List_Cards.AddString(L"Foo");
m_Idc_List_Cards.AddString(L"Bar");
```

Modifying the style didn't do anything.

I can't find any information on the web.

I've even tried to *hold shift* down etc. to select multiple items, but this won't change anything.

## EDIT

When trying to change the Selection property to `multiple`
I get the following error
[image]

Fixed this issue with removing the references and creating a new form from scratch.
Select Mode `multiple` worked then.

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl+Click each item work?

Comment: @sergiol no, it unselects the other item then

Comment: Any reason why you don't simply set this using the dialog editor properties window Selection property?

Comment: @acraig5075 i tried that. See updated question

Comment: Next time when you get such an error message, press Retry to debug the application as the message tells you. Then look at the source code, where the debugger took you, there will be an `ASSERT` call that verifies a condition, often there are also comments in the code near the `ASSERT` that tell you the reason for this check. Another important tool is the call stack window of the debugger. Go down the callstack until you see a function of your own code, this should give you a clue what went wrong in *your* code. I suggest to work through a good tutorial of debugging with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation states clearly that this styles can't be modified after the control was created.

Destroy the old control and create a new one in place.

> To create a list box by using the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function, use the LISTBOX class, appropriate window style constants, and the following style constants to define the list box. **After the control has been created, these styles cannot be modified, except as noted.**

Quote from [the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/list-box-styles)